# Getting coordinates of a touch in React Native (Expo)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I need to get (relative) coordinates of a click/touch in React Native.

I tried using RN `<View onPress={(e: GestureResponderEvent) => ...}>`

On the Web, I further use `e.nativeEvent` which is of the type `PointerEvent`, and I use `layerX, layerY` which give me exactly numbers I need.

Unfortunately, the iOS native event has similar fields named `locationX` and `locationY`.

I have to use this ugly code to get the coordinates

```
interface IEvent {
  layerX?: number
  layerY?: number
  locationX?: number
  locationY?: number
}

const { layerX, layerY, locationX, locationY } =
      e.nativeEvent as unknown as IEvent

const x = layerX ?? locationX
const y = layerY ?? locationY
```

Is there a better cross-platform way of doing it? Perhaps I need to use another control or another event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone needs it.

I changed the event to `onPressIn(e)`. `e.nativeEvent` events consistently using `locationX` and `locationY` across the Web and iOS.

Comment: Same can be used with `onPressOut`, in case you need a location where the touch was released, not started.
And it appears that since 'press' is either in or out, iOS implementation didn't decide which will be used by default with just `onPress` :)